# Android studio error: use -source 9 or higher to enable private interface methods

Tags: java, android

I have this code in Android Studio for one of my app:

```
public abstract interface GNewsEndpoints {
    
    private default java.lang.String getGNewsToken() {
        return null;
    }
    
}
```

I am using Android Studio in MAC OS

I get this error when building the project:

```
error: private interface methods are not supported in -source 8
    private default java.lang.String getGNewsToken() {
                                                  ^
  (use -source 9 or higher to enable private interface methods)
```

Can anyone please suggest what needs to be done in order to fix it?

Comment: I don't think you can use this in Android.

Comment: If I'm right (but to be clear, I don't write Android programs, so I could be wrong), the solution is don't write a private method in an interface.

Comment: Update your JDK to 11, currently, JDK 11 is suggested by google for Android Development.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For more than 25 years everything was done without private interface methods. So maybe instead of

```
public abstract interface GNewsEndpoints {
```

You want

```
public abstract class GNewsEndpoints {
```

That's how it has always been done. If you are sure you want to use interface private methods (which is a quite new Java feature) you can change this in app/build.gradle (X is the Java version):

```
sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_X
targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_X
```

to:

```
sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_9
targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_9
```

Unfortunately I cannot say if you need to set `minSdk` to a minimum version supporting Java 9. It might happen that your app crashes if you try to use Java 9 features on old Android devices.

You can even use `VERSION_1_10` to get Java 10 features.